# SlidingMenu : Showing seconday menu on an event

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using the awesome library [**SlidingMenu**](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/archive/master.zip) by **jfeinstein10**. So, everything is is going just right but one thing.

I am able to open the primary menu using the method `toggle()` in an event handler. But I also want the secondary menu to open on some event like *button click*.

I did something like

```
SlidingMenu right = getSlidingmenu();
right.setSecondaryMenu(rightMenuView)
```

and was thinking of doing `right.toggle();`
but the second statement above throws a NullPointerException.

**Edit : Posting onCreate**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    leftMenuView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_menu, null, false);
    rightMenuView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_menu, null, false);
    customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar,null);

    findAllViews();
    setFontAwesome();

    ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
    ivHome = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ab_home); 
    ivHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Tag");
            toggle();
        }
    });


    leftSlidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();
    leftSlidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    setBehindContentView(leftMenuView);
    leftSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    leftSlidingMenu.setBehindOffset(100);
    leftSlidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);

    rightSlidingMenu = getSlidingMenu();
            rightSlidingMenu.setSecondaryMenu(rightMenuView); //NPE Here
            rightSlidingMenu.toggle();  
}
```

Any idea how to open secondary menu on an event. Thank You

Comment: Can you post the source code. Specifically the onCreate() of the activity that initiates the secondary menu?

Comment: @mach: Posted in the edit

Comment: Got it <code>getSlidingMenu.showSecondaryMenu()</code>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show the second menu you can use:

```
getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu(true);
```

The boolean parameter is the animation flag.

Comment: thanks Masarse your answer really helped me.But i want to disable the secondary menu. I have tried     getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu(false);  ,                      its not working can you please help me.

Comment: @Rojesh The boolean parameter in showSecondaryMenu() is for animation not for closing it.

Comment: use:
if(!sm.isSecondaryMenuShowing()) {
  sm.showSecondaryMenu(true);
}else{
  sm.toggle();
}, sm being getSlidingMenu()

Answer (score 1):

In `BaseActivity` modify as following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    case R.id.github:
        //Util.goToGitHub(this); //remove this line
        showSecondaryMenu(); //add this line
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```